# Java EE Application counters monitoring

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, monitoring

I have a Java EE application deployed on a WebLogic, I have set up a monitoring counters for it, and I got the following results:

[image]

Actually I am not familiar with most of these counters, I have read about most of them but I didn't get how to determine if my app behave in a good way or bad way.

My questions are:

1. How can i know if am doing good (if my app behave in a good way)? is there any spacific numbers to start compare the system behavior from.
2. What is the most important counter that i have to focus on them?
3. Any Idea or Article to help me for understand this counters.

Note: My Server Machine specs are:`(OS:MS Windows server 2008, CPU : Core i7, RAM : 16GB)` AND
JVM Params `(Xmx : 4096, Xms : 1024, -XX:MaxPermSize : 1200, -XX:NewSize : 1200)`

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Plain numbers are not so descriptive as graphical charts. I suggest you to use a tool like `visualvm` from JDK, or `Java Mission Control`. Mission Control is bundled with JDK starting at JDK 7 Update 40. With these tools you can connect to any JVM process, local or remote. If you're connecting to a remote JVM, you should have enabled JMX via JVM parameter `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010`

These tools will allow you to monitor such things like:

- CPU usage
- Memory usage
- All application threads and their states
- GC activities
- etc

All these characteristics are displayed as dynamically changing charts. Moreover, you can create your own controls via JMX beans, and monitor them. For example, you can monitor JDBC connection pools if you create a JMX bean for it.

Answer (score 1):

to monitor weblogic application you can use the [Weblogic Dahsboard](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13714/dashboard.htm) which is more specific for weblogic.
Anyway you have to check the following indicators:

1. Free Heap
2. Thread count
3. Timeout connection from pool
4. Workermanager load
5. Rolled Back transaction
6. Messages on the queue

and finally perform a "thread dump". These indicators provide the right information.

Finally get an eye [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13814.pdf) or http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/perform/topten.html (old for 9 but good).

**Ps**: I work with Oracle guys and I have seen that they do this.